# What is the shortcut to bring up class initializer autocompletion popup? Xcode 9 Swift 4

Tags: syntax, autocomplete, initialization, swift4, xcode9

How can I force Xcode with Swift to bring up the list of initializers/constructors for a class? I know that Control+Space works with a dot syntax: class.[Control+ Space for autocompletion]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0154.png)

**How can I force a swift class to list all possible initializers?**

[image]

It seems that sometimes this works when typing an open parenthesis `String(` . But I've seen this behavior fail in many cases - no suggestions are provided.

Comment: Auto completion on Xcode is a mess. I sometimes have to quit Xcode to get it working again. Hope Xcode 10 improves that.

Comment: Try using .init to see all de initializers for a class